# Database SQLite INSERT

Tags: python, performance, sqlite, query-performance

Can I insert 100k notes in <=1 seconds(database SQLite).I use python library now.My code is here.I have result 100k notes in 1,5 seconds.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('data8.sqlite')
c = conn.cursor()
for i in range(1,100000):
    c.execute('''INSERT INTO data ('val1','val2','val3','val4','val5','val6','val7','val8','val9','val10')\
              VALUES ('%d','%d','%d','%d','%d','%d','%d','%d','%d','%d')''' % (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))

conn.commit()
c.close()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store all data into a list and pass this list to `executemany()`:

```
data = []
for i in range(1, 100000):
    data.append((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))

c.executemany('INSERT INTO data (val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7, val8, val9, val10) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', data)
```

I use the `?` char to prevent the use of string formatting (and it should be used as a best practice).
In my computer, I went from ~ 1 sec to < 0.3 sec.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can but It depends on your machine for example my machine did less than 1 msec and dont use `' '` like this `INSERT INTO data ('val1','val2' ...` use this `INSERT INTO data (val1,val2 ...`:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('data8.sqlite')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data (
            val1 integer,
            val2 integer
        )
""")
for i in range(1,100000):
    c.execute('''INSERT INTO data (val1, val2)\
              VALUES (%d, %d)''' % (1, 2))
row= c.execute("""select count(*) from data""")
print(row.fetchone())
conn.commit()
c.close()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a matter of code, the insert speed is due to several variables:

- PC performances.
- The query itself, it depends on how much values and records you want to insert, the field type and how big is the value you want to insert.
- In case you are inserting rows in an online database, the network connection also does its part.

To see if the speed gets higher, you could try to insert values on a more permormant machine (like a server).